# VS Code, emacs trouble with including header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was using Vs Code and it all was just fine till, i guess, latest update. Now when i have a `function.hh` file in my `.hh` files folder, it does not see it when i try to code in `function.cpp`, of course i `#include "function.hh"`. 
The same problem occurs when a write in terminal with emacs and simply compile with g++. I know about jsonproperites file: I hadn't done anything in it and it allways was fine... no fatal errors.

Also when i open in Vs code my older project that used to work fine with no errors, the message about cannot finding .hh files etc, pops up all over the place, but when i compile it with makefile it works fine.

Comment: Not sure I follow you... VScode update broke g++?

Comment: I know that's almost impossible, but i described it the way it "looks". I am working on macbook pro late 2014, had xcode but i deleted it, in favor of VScode for current needs.

Comment: Looks like this: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/263/q5iduG.png http://imageshack.com/a/img922/3571/db9l24.png http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5629/FIRqD3.png